# C++ optimizations

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm doing some real-time stuff and I need a lot of speed. But in my code, I have this :

```
float maxdepth;
uint32_t faceindex;

for (uint32_t tr_iterator = 0; tr_iterator < facesNum-1; tr_iterator++)
{
    maxdepth = VXTrisDepth[tr_iterator];
    faceindex = tr_iterator;
    uint32_t tr_literator = 3*tr_iterator;
    uint32_t facelindex = 3*faceindex;
    for (uint32_t tr_titerator = tr_iterator+1; tr_titerator < facesNum; tr_titerator++)
    {
        float depth = VXTrisDepth[tr_titerator];
        if (depth > maxdepth)
        {
            maxdepth = depth;
            faceindex = tr_titerator;
        }
    }
    Vei2 itmpx = trs[tr_literator+0];
    trs[tr_literator+0] = trs[facelindex+0];
    trs[facelindex+0] = itmpx;
         itmpx = trs[tr_literator+1];
    trs[tr_literator+1] = trs[facelindex+1];
    trs[facelindex+1] = itmpx;
         itmpx = trs[tr_literator+2];
    trs[tr_literator+2] = trs[facelindex+2];
    trs[facelindex+2] = itmpx;
    float id   = VXTrisDepth[tr_iterator];
    VXTrisDepth[tr_iterator] = VXTrisDepth[faceindex];
    VXTrisDepth[faceindex] = id;
}
```

VXTrisDepth is just an array of float, faceindex is a uint32_t and is a big number, trs is an array of Vei2, and Vei2 is just a integer 2D vector.
The problem is that when we have something like 16074 in facenum, this loop takes 700ms to run on my computer, and that's way too much, any idea of optimizations ?

Comment: Have you tried `-O3` switch?

Comment: Try using std::swap for the whole part where you have the tmp variables

Comment: A possible optimization is to move the 2nd loop out of the 1st loop, the "2nd" loop builds a vector of maxdepth  and faceindex for every tr_titerator and the 1st loop uses it instead of.

Comment: Show your compilation command line; you are building with optimisations on, right? Side note: I find the names `tr_iterator`, `tr_literator`, and `tr_titerator` (or `faceindex` and `facelindex`) extremely confusing, and would reject the code from code review for this reason. Names more distinct at first glance might be better for maintainability.

Comment: @megabyte1024 Actually, the problem with that seems to be that the array `VXTrisDepth` is changing in the outer loop, so inner loop thing may not be precomputable.

Comment: @MMBCProductions It might help us find optimisations if you also told us what the code actually does (in human words).

Comment: Methinks you could eliminate the inner loop entirely if you compute the "maximum from every point" as part of the outer loop. Then you'll reduce to O(N). Nice.

Comment: @Angew, My bad, sorry. Missed code in the the end of the 1st loop. My suggestion is not an option.

Comment: You can reduce the 9 steps to swap values to 8 steps. Is it a way that you want? This can help you reduce the time. **`temp = fo1;
fo1 = ft1;
ft1 = fo3;
fo3 = ft3;
ft3 = temp;
temp = ft2;
ft2 = fo2;
fo2 = temp;`**

Comment: @Bathsheba : It's harder than that; the end of the outer loop can change the maximum.

Comment: Rather than the inner loop, using `std::max` from the algorithm library might help a bit (but it's going to be a few %).

Comment: @MartinBonner: It's well over a days' work, which is why I'm not going to write out the solution; plus the question isn't watertight enough.

Comment: Use parallelization with CUDA or OpenCL, or batch the job with multiple threads.

Comment: Run it with a profiler.  Then evaluate the results to see what costs the most.  Address that.

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten it a bit to find out what you really was doing.

Warning all code is ***untested***

```
float maxdepth;
uint32_t faceindex;

for (uint32_t tr_iterator = 0; tr_iterator < facesNum-1; tr_iterator++) {
    faceindex = tr_iterator;
    uint32_t tr_literator = 3*tr_iterator;
    uint32_t facelindex = 3*faceindex;

    auto fi = std::max_element(&VXTrisDepth[tr_iterator], &VXTrisDepth[facesNum]);
    maxdepth = *fi;
    faceindex = std::distance(&VXTrisDepth[0], fi);

    // hmm was this originally a VEC3...
    std::swap(trs[tr_literator+0], trs[facelindex+0]);
    std::swap(trs[tr_literator+1], trs[facelindex+1]);
    std::swap(trs[tr_literator+2], trs[facelindex+2]);

    // with the above this looks like a struct of arrays. SOA vs AOS
    std::swap(VXTrisDepth[tr_iterator], VXTrisDepth[faceindex]);
}
```

Now it looks like [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) of two arrays which is O(N^2) no wonder it feels slow.

There are multiple methods to sort this

- External index, make an array with length facesNum, initalized from zero to facesNum-1 and sort them using the index into VXTrisDepth. Then reorder the 2 original arrays according to the index array.
- External pair of index and key, to make it easy use std::pair, sort it and then reorder the original 2 arrays.
- sort the 2 arrays as if it was one, slight hack. using std::swap you need to specialize on a type so it can be misused to swap 2 arrays. No extra storage needed.

Lets try an easy version with the external pair.

We need 3 stages

- make helper array O(N)
- sort helper array O(N lg N)
- reorder original arrays O(N)

And some more code

```
// make helper array
using hPair = std::pair<float, int>; // order is important
std::vector<hPair> helper;
helper.reserve(numFaces);

for (int idx = 0; idx < facesNum; idx++)
  helper.emplace_back(VXTrisDepth[idx], idx);

// sort it using std::pair's operator < or write your own
std::sort(helper.begin(), helper.end());

// reorder the SOA arrays
auto vx = std::begin(VXTrisDepth);
for (auto& help : helper) {
  int tr_literator = help.second;
  std::swap(trs[tr_literator+0], trs[facelindex+0]);
  std::swap(trs[tr_literator+1], trs[facelindex+1]);
  std::swap(trs[tr_literator+2], trs[facelindex+2]);

  *vs++ = help.first; // we already have the sorted depth in helper.
  //std::swap(VXTrisDepth[tr_iterator], VXTrisDepth[faceindex]);
}
```

Remember to test that it still works ... you already have a test framework right?